# Sparx Enterprise Architect GetLastError() is always null Java

Tags: java, enterprise-architect

I have some trouble with the Sparx Enterprise Architect Java API. 
Everytime I call the `GetLastError()` function it returns `null` even if there was an error while calling some other functions of the API.

I have no idea how to get the error message. My code looks like this:

```
repository.GetProjectInterface().GetLastError()
```

I am using EA 9.0.

Comment: Can you post the snippet where you think you face with an error but this call doesn't show it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Repository.GetLastError()`
That will probably report something.

Comment: Too bad, might be a bug. Have you reported it to Sparx?

Comment: I haven´t reported this behavior until now. But I think Version 9.0 is out of support.

Comment: Doesn't matter which version. Anyway, errors only get fixed in a new release. Might be worth checking if this is still a problem in v12(.1). If it is then definitely report it. If not then you already know the response from Sparx support -> "upgrade to v12."

Comment: I will give it a try.